# Rails. Validations for many locales at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rails-i18n, globalize3

I have a bilingual web site with two locales: **en** and **ru**.

I want my site to have i18n. I use '**globalize3**' and '**easy_globalize3_accessors**' gems.

There are departments I can create and edit with standard forms.
Locales are given from URL: `example.com/en/departments/` or `example.com/ru/departments/`

Now if I want to create a new department item, I would see such a thing:

1. A main form for current locale (I18n.locale).
2. A checkbox to add a translation **on the same page**.
3. If checkbox is active, show another form for another locale right next to the main form.
4. The most important thing — validations for each locale must be different. Say, for **en** it should pass ASCII symbols; for **ru** — Cyrillic ones.

My problem is number 4. I can't get my validations work with a checkbox.

The main problem is: *checkbox active? If yes, show another form and run validations for it. If no, show nothing and don't run validations for that form, pass it empty.*

For now, if I fill in two forms, everything works like a charm.

Ok. What I tried.

**Model**

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :translations_attributes
  translates :name, fallbacks_for_empty_translations: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :translations

  # The inline class Translation is a hack to solve 
  # "Can't mass-assign protected attributes: locale"
  # See https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3/issues/128#issuecomment-11480650
  class Translation
    attr_accessible :locale, :name
    validates :name, uniqueness: true
    validates :name, format: {with: /\A[-а-яА-Я -]+\Z/},  if: ->(l) {l.locale.to_s == 'ru'}
    validates :name, format: {with: /\A[-a-zA-Z -']+\Z/}, if: ->(l) {l.locale.to_s == 'en'} 
  end
end
```

**Controller**

```
def new
  @department = Department.new
end

def create
  @department = Department.new(params[:department])
  @department.save ? (redirect_to action: :index) : (render :new)
end
```

**View (new.haml.html) without checkbox**

```
= form_for @department, url: {action: :create} do |f|
  %h2
    - f.globalize_fields_for_locale I18n.locale do |g|
      = "Translation for"
      = I18n.locale
      = g.label t("department.form.new.label.name")
      = g.text_field :name
  %hr
  %h2
    - I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
      - next if locale == I18n.locale
      %br
      - f.globalize_fields_for_locale locale do |g|
        = "Translation for"
        = locale
        = g.label t("department.form.new.label.name")
        = g.text_field :name

  = f.submit t("department.create.link"), class: "btn"
```

Help me understand what I have to do, please.